# Ruby+imenu not showing private methods

Tags: imenu, ruby

I'm a little surprised that I haven't found anything on the web about this, but I've got a Ruby file and its private methods aren't listed by imenu.

Given the following class:

```ruby
class Blub
  def hi
    "Hi!"
  end
  def bye
    "Bye!"
  end

  private
  
  def hiding
    "You can't see me"
  end
end
```

you can reproduce this by running `M-x` `imenu`, which doesn't show `hiding`, while `hi` and `bye` are there.

This is the case whether I start emacs normally or with `--no-init`.

Any ideas?

In larger buffers where I want to navigate within it, this would be a valuable fix.

Here's the version info my emacs. I'm on arch linux.

```sh
$ emacs --version
GNU Emacs 27.2
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GNU Emacs comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You may redistribute copies of GNU Emacs
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING.
```

### Update

I've gotten a bit further. The original version of my sample class was incorrect, which is why [@Dmitry](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/124/dmitry) and [@Étienne](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/28767/%c3%89tienne) weren't able to reproduce the problem.

When we use [inline access modifiers](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/cops_style.html#enforcedstyle-inline), as in the example below, the problem should be reproducible when emacs is started with either the -q or -Q option.

```ruby
class Blub
  def hi
    "Hi!"
  end

  def bye
    "Bye!"
  end

  private def hiding
    "You can't see me"
  end
end
```

I'm still not sure how to fix this though. A quick look into the imenu source makes me think it has to do with the `imenu-create-index-function`, which I'd guess has to be defined for each language, but that's as far as I've gotten at this point.

Comment: Works for me here. Which Emacs version is this?

Comment: It also works for me. Looking at [the code](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/progmodes/ruby-mode.el#n677) it is very straightforward and does not do anything about private methods. At least for the default `ruby-mode`. Maybe do you use another mode on top of it?

Comment: Weird. I've updated the question. The version is 27.2 on arch linux.

Comment: I see you have tried it with `emacs -q`. Can you try `emacs -Q` instead? That would also disable extra Lisp installed by the system.

Comment: See the update I've posted. Sorry, the original version of my example class was not correct :(

Comment: @flooose Now I see it, thanks. Could you `M-x report-emacs-bug`, so we can fix this for Emacs 28, at least?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now fixed in `ruby-mode` on master, for the upcoming Emacs 28.

If you are staying on a release version, you can apply this patch locally: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=9e2cc406d3bc1a1f2f6008059091b9c1b8f12acf